# Joining multiple sql statements

Tags: sql, oracle, union

```
SELECT column_a1,column_b1,column_c1,column_d1,column_e1,column_f1,column_g1 
FROM mytable WHERE id=12 AND detectcolumn=1  

UNION ALL

SELECT column_a2,column_b2,column_c2,column_d2,column_e2,column_f2 
FROM mytable WHERE id=12 AND detectcolumn=2 

UNION ALL

SELECT column_a3,column_b3,column_c3,column_d3,column_e3,column_f3,column_g3
FROM mytable WHERE id=12 AND detectcolumn=3 

UNION ALL

SELECT column_a4 from mytable WHERE id=12 AND detectcolumn=4 

UNION ALL

SELECT column_a5 from mytable WHERE id=12 AND detectcolumn=5 

UNION ALL

SELECT column_a6 from mytable WHERE id=12 AND detectcolumn=6 

UNION ALL

SELECT column_a7 from mytable WHERE id=12 AND detectcolumn=7
```

How shall i combine all these sql statements into one single sql statement.I want to get particular columns from mytable depending on value of detectcolumn.

I tried using UNION ALL but it gives error **ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns**

Comment: each union select sentence must have identical field count. your union does not meet this requirement. try to explain what you are going to get.

Comment: I want to get particular columns from **mytable** depending on value of **detectcolumn**

Comment: Put that in the question, not as a comment

Comment: You could add blank columns for the queries with less columns.

Comment: How many total columns do you want your result table to have?

Comment: the toal columns are 24.

Answer (score 2):

Use a pattern such as:

```
 select
   case detectcolumn
     when 4 then column_a4
     when 5 then column_a5
     when 6 then column_a6
   end
 from
   my_table
 where
   id           = 12 and
   detectcolumn in (4,5,6)
```

Comment: how shall i provide multiple columnnames after **then**

Comment: Which columns do you want? Please update the question to be more specific

Comment: how shall i write multiple columns when **detectcolumn=1**

Comment: Use the same CASE function for every column you want to output